# Find All Items In RichTextBox

Tags: string, vb.net, search, find, richtextbox

I have a `.css` file and I want to find all strings that start with `/images_rtl/` and end with `.png`, then add them in list box.

What sort of code would be required to program this?

Comment: What is the definitive way of telling when a new string starts? Are strings on their own lines? Or are the separated by a set character?

Comment: @David No, Its not separated or start in new lines it have many codes and i just want to find all like this : `/image_rtl/ ??? .png`

Comment: @David its my http://cdn.traviantools.net/game/0.62/layout/css/ltr.css css file Check it Please

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this...

```
    For Each item In RichTextBox1.Lines
        ' See if input matches one of these starts.
        If item.StartsWith("/images_rtl/") AndAlso item.EndsWith(".png") Then
            listbox1.items.add(item)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: It's my css file : http://cdn.traviantools.net/game/0.62/layout/css/ltr.css . Your code doesn't work for me !

Comment: Read the can file into the rich text box and it will